# How to fetch records based on month and year using jenssegers/mongodb package in laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

is there any simmilar methods available in jenssegers/mongodb

for ex .

$products = DB::table('products')->whereMonth('created_at','09')->get();

now i m getting
 Error is:
Call to undefined method Jenssegers\Mongodb\Query\Builder::compileWhereMonth()

Comment: which version of jenssegers?

Comment: i was use  Jenssegers version 3.2